# MongoDB query for specific results

Tags: mongodb

My mindset keeps thinking in sql to do this and can't seem to get a full grip on using the mongodb shell to get the answers i want. I have a collection in which i would like to return multiple pieces of information from which i will export into a csv file.

This is the collection i am looking at:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("32eri3u8euhf748303"),
"email" : "userEmail@email.com",
"firstName" : "John",
"lastName" : "Johnson",
"classes" : {
    "kjsfd434892e38dsidf8e920" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("kjsfd434892e38dsidf8e920"),
        "className" : "English 101"
     }
 }
```

I have a list of users and some users can have more than one class. How do i write up my query statement so i can return the names, email address and classes for all users?

Comment: I may not be understanding your question correctly, but if all you want is a command for the shell that returns all the properties for all the documents in that collection, you can just use `db.users.find()`

Comment: @jaimeRodas yes i want to a proper format find statement to get these results that i want to export to a csv. I am new to mongo so what i am reading is very basic and it feels very different from sql

Comment: you should look into `mongoexport` https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, use this :

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/database_name';
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connection established to', url);

var collection = db.collection('users');

collection.find({}, {"classes.kjsfd434892e38dsidf8e920.className": 1}).toArray(function (err, users) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else if (users.length) {
    console.log('Found:', users);
  } else {
    console.log('No users found');
  }
  db.close();
});
}
});
```

Comment: isn't this just returning the number of users in the collection? I would like to return certain fields within the collection and i wanted to know how to specify which fields i could return.

Comment: No. This will return all the users in the users collection. Now if you want to get only some fields, then use a projection document. Something like this : `collection.find({}, {name :1, address: 1}).toArray(function(){ //code to handle the response })`

Comment: Thank you for your help i am starting to get this more and more. One more question. in `name:1` what does the 1 mean?

Comment: It tells mongodb to include certain fields. The _id field is included by default. So you can simply include  the fields you want by giving them a value of 1 and exclude fields that you don't want by giving them a value of 0, in this projection document.

Comment: So with my example if i have multiple fields in my classes and i want to return just the className how can i do that without having to return all the other fields? like classes.className

Comment: Just do a `classes.classname:1` and you'll get it.

Comment: I did try that but i got an error. Could it be because i className is within a returned object so i would have to access the object itself for get to the name within?

Comment: Great thanks but this only works perfectly if i have a single class but not multiple classes for a user.

Comment: Then maybe you should change the way the `classes` are stored in your case. I can't see why you have stored the class' ObjectId as a key. Something like this can simplify things for you : 

`"_id" : ObjectId("32eri3u8euhf748303"),
"email" : "userEmail@email.com",
"firstName" : "John",
"lastName" : "Johnson",
"classes" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("kjsfd434892e38dsidf8e920"),
    "className" : "English 101"
 }`

That way you won't have to determine the ObjectId each time for each document. You will just be able to project out class name by

`{"classes.className": 1}`